# HttpWebRequest Proxy and HttpListener

Tags: c#

I am attempting to redirect an HttpWebRequest to a mock service dependency set up using an HttpListener.

I have tried the following: create a WebProxy and set the proxy URL to the URL of my mock service dependency. What I have observed is that when the proxy is set to a port other than 80 I get an HTTP 400 Bad Request. When the port is set to 80 I get a 404 Not Found error. I confirmed that accessing the dependency directly (without the use of the proxy - i.e.: by hardcoding the mock url) works correctly.

Is it possible to get this to work using HttpListener as the mock dependency and a WebProxy? If not, are there any other practical ways in C# to redirect all HttpWebRequests to a given set of URLs? I would like to avoid changing the path that the HttpWebRequests are created with. I have no requirement for HTTPS support.

Comment: You get a bad request because when a proxy is specified, and you request htt p://localhost:1456/default.aspx for example, the request is formed as [GET htt p://localhost:1456/default.aspx HTTP/1.1], while without a proxy it would be [GET /default.aspx HTTP/1.1]

Comment: Therefore, I recommend using Fiddler 2, and you don't even have to specify the proxy yourself because your http client will get it from winhttp automatically. Using fiddler, you can redirect your requests to your mock service. [Check this documentation for Fiddler](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse)

Comment: Indeed. The next option I was considering was to use FiddlerCore in my application and set it up to proxy the requests to the affected URLs. The main concern I have is that these tests will run in a specialized test environment and I am not convinced that I will be able to get Fiddler working in this environment.

Comment: You don't have to. You can have Fiddler running in another environment, and only for testing (on the specialized test environment) can specify the proxy to point to the server where Fiddler runs. I don't think you should go for FiddlerCore just to redirect some requests to another host

Comment: Fiddler has an "Allow remote computers to connect" option.